# How to modify an integer object attached to a stringlist item?

Tags: delphi

If I have a stringlist that 'contains' a number of items that have been added via

`StringList.AddObject('somestring', TObject(1));`

how can I change the integer object for an item to some other integer?

Comment: `StringList.Objects[3] := TObject(394)`

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand not 42!?

Comment: No, I tend to use 394 as my standard "random" number.